# Migrating to Jersey 2.x getting 404 errors while calling my api's

Tags: java, web-services, rest, servlets, jersey-2.0

I am migrating from com.sun.jersey 1.x to org.glassfish.jersey 2.x,

my web.xml looks like:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!-- Bean Configuration -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:application-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
    <param-value>webservices</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.jersey.series.spring.security.service</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.xyz.webservices</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <!-- Enable / Disable Jersey Tracing and Logging. -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.tracing</param-name>
        <param-value>${jersey.enable.trace}</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.disable.wadl</param-name>
        <param-value>${jersey.disable.wadl}</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

So the resources defined under com.xyz.webservices.resources, whenever are called like '/app/api/data' says 404 page not found. Am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: I don't know if you can use the same init param twice, but you can just use it once, and separate two values with a comma or a semi-colon. Try to do that.

Comment: Tried that it is still throwing me this error: Jersey exception has been thrown
javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found
 at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:323)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope

Answer (score 0):

I got the code working by modifying my web.xml as:

```
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.jersey.series.spring.security.service,com.xyz.webservices</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <!-- Enable / Disable Jersey Tracing -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.tracing</param-name>
        <param-value>${jersey.enable.trace}</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.disable.wadl</param-name>
        <param-value>${jersey.disable.wadl}</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <!-- Enabling Jackson Feature and Logging -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature,org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter,org.glassfish.jersey.server.filter.EncodingFilter,org.glassfish.jersey.message.DeflateEncoder,org.glassfish.jersey.message.GZipEncoder</param-value>
    </init-param>
```